# Variable for "ID" in delete call to endpoint is set to "undefined" even when I have an ID variable added

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, rest, swagger

So I have a webapplication that is using axios to make endpoint request to my api that is on Swagger. In my app currently get and post calls work but not puts or deletes.

For my delete call I pass the userID into the ID field in the URL:

```
const onDelete = (userId) => {
        axios.delete(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users/${userId}`)
            .then(() => {
                getData();
            })
    }
```

But in the console it shows the following two errors:

```
DELETE https://localhost:44373/api/Users/undefined 400 xhr.js:210
```

and:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

This is my full "ReadUser" file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';




export default function Read() {

    const setData = (data) => {
        let { userId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, password } = data;
        localStorage.setItem('UserId', userId);
        localStorage.setItem('First Name', firstName);
        localStorage.setItem('Last Name', lastName);
        localStorage.setItem('EmailAddress', emailAddress);
        localStorage.setItem('Phonenumber', phoneNumber);
        localStorage.setItem('Password', password)
    }

    const url = `https://localhost:44373/api/Users`;
    const getData = () => {
        axios.get(url)
            .then((getData) => {
                setAPIData(getData.data);
            })
    }

    const onDelete = (userId) => {
        axios.delete(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users/${userId}`)
            .then(() => {
                getData();
            })
    }

    const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users`)
            .then((response) => {
                setAPIData(response.data);
            })
    }, [])

  

    return (

        <div>
            <Table bordered>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th key="firstName">First Name</th>
                        <th key="lastName">Last Name</th>
                        <th key="emailAddress">Emailaddress</th>
                <th key="phoneNumber">Phonenumber</th>
                        <th>Update</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {APIData.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{data.firstName}</td>
                                <td>{data.lastName}</td>
                                <td>{data.emailAddress}</td>
                                <td>{data.phoneNumber}</td>
                                <td><Link to='/UpdateUser'><td><button className="table-btn" onClick={() => setData(data)}>Update</button></td></Link></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button className="table-btn" onClick={() => onDelete(data.id)}>Delete</button>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also I keep getting "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

But as far as I can tell I have added the correct keys? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss to add `userId` in `axios.put` request body. Example:

```
const updateAPIData = () => {
        axios.put(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users/${userId}`, {
            userId,
            lastName,
            emailAddress,
            phoneNumber,
            password
        }).then(() => {
            navigate('/ReadUser')
        })
    }

 const onDelete = (userId) => {
    axios.delete(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users/${userId}`, { data: { userId }})
        .then(() => {
            getData();
        })
  }
```

It's how to fix problem with keys in JSX:

```
 {APIData.map((data, index) => {
                    return (
                        <tr key={index}>
                           ....
                           <button className="table-btn" onClick={() => onDelete(data.userId)}>Delete</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks! This worked, however now I get another error that : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLButtonElement'
    |     property '__reactFiber$4q4iyvka2lq' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you mind explaining how to do that? I get that I should: const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj); I just dont understand where to do that in my code. T

Comment: I have typo, updated answer

Comment: The same problem with delete call, because you don't set id to request body. In your server code you check id's for similarity

Comment: Edited answer with more info

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and help! However I still get the same issue that it returns the ID as undefined. I updated my "onDelete" function:    const onDelete = (userId) => {
        axios.delete(`https://localhost:44373/api/Users/${userId}`, { data: { userId } })
            .then(() => {
                getData();
            })
    } but i still get the same error: xhr.js:210 DELETE https://localhost:44373/api/Users/undefined 400

Comment: So, you have problem with `APIData`, can you check it

Comment: You may be using the wrong key , try `onDelete(data.userId)` instead of `onDelete(data.id)`

Comment: I'm able to use swagger "execute" on my delete call and if I add an ID from an existing user into the ID field it deletes the corresponding user from the DB

Comment: I think you do mistake here `onDelete(data.id)`, if you look at the code above, you use `userId` but not `id`. Try `onDelete(data.userId)` instead of `onDelete(data.id)`

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this! However I cannot use data.userId (I get that it is a syntax error). Do you mean that I should use "id" instead of "userId" in the onDelete function? Becuase neither one of them work it is still sending "xhr.js:210 DELETE https://localhost:44373/api/Users/undefined" could this be beacuse of cors preflight?

Comment: So if I use "userId" or "id" i still get that I'm sending "undefined" and the name for the id is "userId" in sql

Comment: Can you console.log `APIData` ? It's not about cors preflight

Comment: I fetch the data like this:     const setData = (data) => {
        let { userId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, password } = data;
        localStorage.setItem('UserId', userId);
        localStorage.setItem('First Name', firstName);
        localStorage.setItem('Last Name', lastName);
        localStorage.setItem('EmailAddress', emailAddress);
        localStorage.setItem('Phonenumber', phoneNumber);
        localStorage.setItem('Password', password)
    }

Comment: Yes one sec! :)

Comment: This is what gets loged: {userId: 1006, firstName: 'Daniel', lastName: 'Svensson', emailAddress: 'daniel@gmail', phoneNumber: '0759012387', …} and it matches the DB

Comment: Look, your data haven't property `id`, but you use it here `onDelete(data.id)`, `data.id` is `undefined`

Comment: You must use `userId` instead of `id`

Comment: Not in `onDelete` function, but in the JSX where you call it `<button className="table-btn" onClick={() => onDelete(data.userId)}>Delete</button>`

Comment: Omg haha facepalm... Thanks so much for your help and patience! :)

Comment: everything already working?

Comment: I'm able to make delete calls now without any issue. I still get "Converting circular structure to JSON" when I make a put call though

Answer (score 1):

It could be cors.

I had the same issue some time ago. Everything worked fine with postman but not with google chrome.

The problem comes from the fact that when sending methods other than get and post your browser will send a preflight request to make sure you are authorized to make the request.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

[How to handle preflight CORS request using Node server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663888/how-to-handle-preflight-cors-request-using-node-server)

For the unique key:
When you map an array, each element should have a unique key prop.

In your case your should have

```
<tr key={unique_key}>
```

The best practice would be to use the id of the element in your db for example:

```
<tr key={data.id}>
```

You could use the array index but it would be bad practice since it could change and introduce bugs in your application.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it! :)